# How to delete an individual cell of table in libreoffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a table with 2 rows. I would like to delete one empty cell in the row in order that the information in the table matches 1:1 by row.

For example:
[image: screenshot]

In the example, I would like to delete the empty cell in the left row so that “Kas mulle makstakse osalemise eest?” would be put automatically instead the empty cell and all the text under this phrase will be automatically put up by 1 cell. At the same time, the text and rows will preserve their position and content.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I fixed it by copy/pasting the 2 rows from LibreOffice Writer to Libeoffice Calc and right-clicking on a cell needing deletion and choosing Delete and "shift cell up" and clicking OK.